# How to Use General Operators in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I do not know how to ask it right

I use a formula to summarize values within a certain range

And I have two questions

F1 contains the value I want to summarize, if I write "*", it summarizes everything, but without empty cells

"E" contains the first-last date to summarize, what the parameter to summarize all dates? (* Does not work)

That's my formula

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B8,A1:A8,">="&E1,A1:A8,"<="&E2,c1:c8,F1)
```

explanation:
"A" contains the dates,
"B" contains the amounts,
"C" contains the values,
"E" contains the first-last date in summary

Sometimes I want to summarize everything regardless of the date, value of the cell

I have other parameters that are not related here

If it is not clear, respond to me

[image]

Comment: Your question might be more clear if you if you include a sample of your data and what you need it to look like in the end.  See how to create an [mcve] **[mcve]** and take a look at this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Comment: But are you saying that if there are blank cells in column C then you also want those rows including in the sum if F1 contains "*"?

Comment: And is the asterisk in F1 also to apply to the dates? Or do you intend to use a different cell to indicate that all dates should be considered?

Comment: But if the same cell (F1) is to be used to indicate both all dates and all entries in column C, then you can precede your formula with a simple IF statement, viz `=IF(F1="*",SUM(B1:B12),SUMIFS(B1:B12,A1:A12,">="&E1,A1:A12,"<="&E2,C1:C12,F1))`.

Comment: The formula works because if cell F1 contains "*" then the formula simply sums the contents of column B.

Comment: slomo take a look at my answer, I've adapted the sumproduct to work exacly as you want

Comment: They all give the right answers and really want to help me, but I have a lot of parameters in the formula, which seems to have to do a very long formula

Comment: Could you explain why the formula I posted does not do as desired?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Both solutions thus far proposed work on the data you provided. Perhaps you have made the mistake of posting an unrealistic and/or incomplete dataset. If so, I suggest you amend your post to include one which is more representative of your actual set-up. We can only go with what you give us.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should use `SUMPRODUCT`, so you can just eliminate any of your criteria using `IF`'s inside.

For example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8*(IF(ISNUMBER(E2)=TRUE,A2:A8>=E2,1))*(IF(ISNUMBER(E3)=TRUE,A2:A8<=E3,1))*(C2:C8=D1))
```

You can make the `IF`'s you want. I've used `ISNUMBER` but you can just make a list validation and insert a "All Dates" and pass this to the `IF` test. Remember to close with ctrl+shift+enter.

**EDIT:** as now I have some of your data and now can understand better you request, I have adapted the formula to work as you need. Wrapped both `IF`'s in one, which will check if F1 has "*" in it's value.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B8)*(IF(F1="*",1,(A2:A8>=E1)*(A2:A8<=E2)*(C2:C8=F1))))
```

EDIT: forgot parentheses inside the if

newer EDIT: adapted the formula to what I think OverflowStack is trying to tell me (sorry people, my english understanding is not that good...), now if F1 is a value contained in the C column, it will return that sum summarized between dates, if the value is "*" it will return the total count.

If it's still not what OP needs, I could probably do better if I can access a dummy sheet of his data on Excel Online, with his variables and desired output example.

Comment: I would guess the answer is not marked as solution, because the formlua still needs some logic to get the sum for a specific direction ("south", ...) or string ("ABC"). And an empty cell check is missing.

Comment: I think you're right and edited, but I think I'm not getting what empty cell I should check.